# Bada scaling question

Tags: font-size, bada

I'm developing a reader application for [Bada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bada_%28operating_system%29) and have a silly question.

*Does a smooth way to convert `pt` size to `pixel` size exist?*

I found something like [this](http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/points-pixels.html), but I'm still hoping you could apply some formula and be happy with it.

Comment: I'm VTCing this as it appears to be both not about programming and also requesting some sort of off-site tool/resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points are a "real-world" length unit (they are generally defined as 1/72 in), but pixels do not have a definite real world size, since this depends on the resolution of the device.

For example, the pixels on my screen are about 0.3 mm wide, while the ones of my phone are about 0.15 mm, and the "pixels" of my laser printer are 0.02 mm wide. Thus, to go from pixels to real world units, you need the resolution of the specific device, i.e. the pixels/real world unit ratio, which, most often, is expressed in DPI (dots per inch, where "dot" is intended as "pixel" for devices that work with pixels).

When dealing with printing/scanning devices the "real world size" is important, so it's almost always provided by the OS in some way and is correct; on the other hand, with screens the situation is quite different.

In most situations you don't really care about the "real world size" of stuff displayed on screens, since no one is ever really measuring anything on the screen. Also, onscreen layouts are often partly done in pixels for a variety of reasons (simplicity being the first).

On the other way, text and other elements' sizes are often specified in points, twips and other "real world units", and in general good window layouts should be done in "real world units" to be easily adapted to screens with high pixel densities, where pixel-based layouts would be unreadable.

For this reason, the OS usually provides a DPI value for the screen, but in general it's left to the same default value (usually 72 DPI) regardless of the real attached screen (also to avoid breaking badly designed interfaces), but leaving it configurable to the user, to let him adjust it to a comfortable value.

As for Bada, I read [here](http://developer.bada.com/badaforum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=developer-site&messageId=28875&startPage=2&curPage=4) that the OS does not provide neither a real neither a "fake" DPI value, so there's no real way to convert from points to pixels. On the other hand, you could simply use the usual "default" 72 DPI value for your conversions. Notice that 72 DPI wasn't chosen by chance: since there are 72 pixels per inch, and 72 points per inch, you simply assume that a point is equal to a pixel. Not correct, but in your case "good enough".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 72 DPI for bada is not a good choice since modern mobile devices have DPIs around 200-300.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Bada wanted to go iPhone way, and have a few devices and you would release your application on each device, which has fixed features. This way, you can visit samsung web, read real size of their screen. Then compute real DPI yourself for each device and store it to table. Runtime, you can get device name and try to search your table.

AFAIK you have to upload your application to bada shop for each device separately. And they assume from Bada SDK that you will compile for each target different application. Target is specified by screen resolution, and I guess you can expect real screen to be this size.

Well, i think think this design is stupid, but might be really the way how they expect you to develop for their platform.